# Compare column to range and delete between multiple sheets in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare two lists of products. I want to delete the entire row in Sheet1 if a match is made from Sheet2.

Sheet1 (has 17226 rows)

```
ITEMID     WAREHOUSEID     QUANTITY     UNIT     PRICE     LOCATIONID
1000       1               100          EA       1.00      30
1001       1               100          EA       1.00      30
1002       1               100          EA       1.00      30
1003       1               100          EA       1.00      30
1004       1               100          EA       1.00      30
1005       1               100          EA       1.00      30
1006       1               100          EA       1.00      30
1007       1               100          EA       1.00      30
1008       1               100          EA       1.00      30
```

Sheet2 (has 977 rows)

```
1002
1004
1006
1008
```

I believe it'd work if I iterate through the values in Column A of Sheet2 and compare them against each ITEMID in Sheet1 (this is Column E in Sheet1).

I wrote this code, but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
Sub Delete()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range
    LastRow = Range("Sheet1!E17226").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each rngCell In Range("Sheet2!A1:A977")
        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            If Range("E" & i).Value = rngCell.Value Then
                Range("E" & i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Please point out my mistake so I can fix and run the VBA script, thank you.

Comment: Use `Application.Match` or `Application.CountIf` to "find" the value from Sheet1 in Sheet2. if not found, delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Delete Rows

**Basic (Two Loops)**

```vb
Sub BasicTwoLoops() ' slow (takes forever)
    
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    Const sCol As String = "A"
    
    Const dfRow As Long = 2
    Const dCol As String = "E"
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Sheet2
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Sheet1
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim sValue As Variant
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dValue As Variant
    Dim dr As Long
    
    For dr = dlRow To dfRow Step -1
        dValue = dws.Cells(dr, dCol).Value
        For sr = sfRow To slRow
            sValue = sws.Cells(sr, sCol).Value
            If dValue = sValue Then
                dws.Cells(dr, dCol).EntireRow.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next sr
    Next dr

End Sub
```

**`Application.Match` feat. `Range.Union`**

```vb
Sub UseRangesWithUnion() ' fast
 ' Uses 'RefCombinedRange'
    
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    Const sCol As String = "A"
    
    Const dfRow As Long = 2
    Const dCol As String = "E"
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Sheet2
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = slRow - sfRow + 1
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Cells(sfRow, sCol).Resize(srCount)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Sheet1
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dlRow - dfRow + 1
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Cells(dfRow, dCol).Resize(drCount)
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sIndex As Variant
    Dim ddrg As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim dValue As Variant
    
    For Each dCell In drg.Cells
        dValue = dCell.Value
        sIndex = Application.Match(dValue, srg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(sIndex) Then
            Set ddrg = RefCombinedRange(ddrg, dCell)
        End If
    Next dCell
    
    If ddrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ddrg.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to a range combined from two ranges.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefCombinedRange( _
    ByVal CombinedRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    If CombinedRange Is Nothing Then
        Set RefCombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set RefCombinedRange = Union(CombinedRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```

**`Range.AutoFilter`**

```vb
Sub UseAutoFilter() ' fastest
' Uses 'GetColumnRange'
' Uses 'ArrStringDataColumn'
' Source headers are not included in the range.
' Destination headers are included in the range.
    
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    Const sCol As String = "A"
    
    Const dfRow As Long = 1 ' Headers included
    Const dCol As String = "E"
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Sheet2
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Sheet1

    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = slRow - sfRow + 1
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Cells(sfRow, sCol).Resize(srCount)
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = GetColumnRange(srg) ' 2D one-based
    Dim sArr As Variant: sArr = ArrStringDataColumn(sData, 1) ' 1D zero-based
    If IsEmpty(sArr) Then Exit Sub
    
    If dws.AutoFilterMode Then
        dws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dlRow - dfRow + 1
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Cells(dfRow, dCol).Resize(drCount)
    Dim ddrg As Range: Set ddrg = drg.Resize(drg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    drg.AutoFilter 1, sArr, xlFilterValues
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ddrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    dws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a column of a 2D array, converted to 
'               a string, in an array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function ArrStringDataColumn( _
    ByVal sData As Variant, _
    ByVal sColumnIndex As Long, _
    Optional ByVal dFirstIndex As Long) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "ArrDataColumn"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim sLower As Long: sLower = LBound(sData, 1)
    Dim sUpper As Long: sUpper = UBound(sData, 1)
    
    Dim IndexDiff As Long: IndexDiff = sLower - dFirstIndex
    Dim dArr As Variant: ReDim dArr(dFirstIndex To sUpper - IndexDiff)
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = sLower To sUpper
        dArr(r - IndexDiff) = CStr(sData(r, sColumnIndex))
    Next r
    
    ArrStringDataColumn = dArr

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the values from a column ('ColumnNumber')
'               of a range ('rg') to a 2D one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetColumnRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnNumber As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If ColumnNumber < 1 Then Exit Function
    If ColumnNumber > rg.Columns.Count Then Exit Function
    
    With rg.Columns(ColumnNumber)
        If rg.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
            GetColumnRange = Data
        Else
            GetColumnRange = .Value
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Nice & helpful tutorial +:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

Note how explicit the `Range` references are. For example, where you have `If Range("E" & i).Value` in your code, that Range object implicitly attaches to the `ActiveSheet`, which could be Shee1 or Sheet2.

```
Public Sub Delete()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A17226")
    Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A997")
    
    For Each r2 In rng2
        Set r1 = rng1.Find(What:=r2.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not r1 Is Nothing Then
            r1.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `r2`probably contains unique values, while `r1` contains multiple occurrences of some of those values. With `Range.Find` you are only finding the first occurrence, which could be fixed by doing `For Each r1 in rng1.Cells...` (also by using `FindNext`). Then you would have another problem, namely, when two critical (matching) cells are consecutive, the second cell would be skipped which you can solve by using `Range.Union`.

Comment: I’m well aware of the occasions where my code does and doesn’t work. This is a simple fix which should work with the example data given. At no point did OP state that the products will be found multiple times in sheet1. I don’t think it’s helpful to add comments to other people’s answer which create issues with them just for the sake of it. I considered UNION but left it out for simplicity. I also considered autofilter and, while I think it’s the best solution and I’m glad you’ve provided it, I thought it would benefit OP well to see an example similar to their attempt.